# Unable to read data from Java Console class. (I'm using Eclipse to run it!!)

Tags: java, java-console

I'm unable to run this code correctly.. Please help me out

```
public static void main(String[] args){     
     Console console = System.console();    // unable to fetch anything. It returns null
    if (console == null) {
        System.out.println("Unable to fetch console");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");   //compiler doesn't come till here 
    String n=console.readLine();    
    System.out.println("Welcome "+n);   
}
```

Comment: Just so you know the `Console` is not the same as the command line.  Maybe look at `System.in` and couple it with a `Scanner` instead

Comment: Actually, you are running it correctly, it's just that the behavior of the code doesn't match your expectations. As MadProgrammmer already said, use an instance of Scanner instead